# cmake ExternalProject_Add how to download URL non-tar file?

Tags: cmake, catch-unit-test

How does one set up an External project to download a link that isn't a .tgz file?

For example [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) provides a release that is a single header distribution.  I would like to just download this rather than the git repo or the .tgz release.  But I haven't figured out how to tell CMake to do this.

I would like to do something like:

```
Include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    catch
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/catch
    URL https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/releases/download/v1.9.6/catch.hpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/catch
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
)
```

This fails as URL assumes that url is a compressed tar file.  I have tried various variants of the **DOWNLOAD_COMMAND** without any success either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use *DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT* option of `ExternalProject_Add`:

> Just download the file and do not extract it; the full path to the downloaded file is available as <DOWNLOADED_FILE>.

Code example:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    catch
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/catch
    URL https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/releases/download/v1.9.6/catch.hpp
    DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT 1
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
```

File will be downloaded into `<prefix>/src` directory.

---

If use *LOG_DOWNLOAD* option alongside with *DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT*, you need CMake 3.9 for work correctly. See these bugreports: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16544, https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17046.

Comment: Thanks.  That's just what I was looking for.  Also thanks for the tip about LOG_DOWNLOAD.  The file was downloading fine.  However,  CMake was failing after the download until I turned off the LOG_DOWNLOAD.  I was even using CMakeLists 3.8.2.  So it looks like it might be broken again.

Comment: Followup on the CMake issue.  This is fixed in CMake 3.9 and it has been back-patched into the 3.8 tree, so if there is another 3.8 release (ie. 3.8.3) it should be fixed there, too. For more info:  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17046#note_289032

Comment: @Tal: Thanks, I have fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Should be DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT 1